# Sencha Touch: How to load controller dynamically

Tags: extjs, sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2

I am building a sencha touch application, in which I have requirement to load controller dynamically mean (programmatically), not through defining it in app.js.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this code:

```
Ext.require(controller, function() {//controller - "App.controller.Name"
    var c = Ext.create(controller, {application: this}), controllers;
    c.init();
    c.launch();
    /*
    The "getController" returns "undefined" for a dynamically loaded controller, so the "controllerInstances" should be updated.
    */
    controllers = this.getControllerInstances();
    controllers[controller] = c;
    this.setControllerInstances(controllers);
}, this.getApplication());
```

Comment: Did this work out for you? I need to do something similar. My controller is located in the Controllers directory and this method didn't seem to work for me when I ran it inside a view's initialize listener.

Comment: This worked for me, but I didn't use all of the example. I just used the `Ext.create(...)` line and then the 3 lines that added the controller to the `ControllerInstances` collection. The value I used for the controller name in  `controllers[controller]` is just the 'Name' part of the controller class name (everything after the 'App.controller.' part)